# GCP Impersonation not working with BQ command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, impersonation

I am trying to use impersonation while using BQ command but getting below error.

This is the command i am trying to run:

```
gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account sa-account  ;\
gcloud config list ; \
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "SELECT * from prj-name.dataset-name.table-name ORDER BY Version" ;\
```

This is the error i am getting:

```
Your active configuration is: [default]
+ bq query --use_legacy_sql=false SELECT * from xxx-prj.dataset-name.table-name ORDER BY Version
ERROR: (bq) gcloud is configured to impersonate service account [XXXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com] but impersonation support is not available.
```

what change is needed here?

Comment: If it's not supported, you can't do so much., but you can perform the query through the API if you want!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use service account impersonation with [BigQuery API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) in gcloud CLI:

1. Impersonate the relevant service account:

   ```
   gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
   ```
2. Run the following CURL command, specifying your `PROJECT_ID` and `SQL_QUERY`:

   ```
   curl --request POST \
   'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT_ID/queries' \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
     -H 'Accept: application/json' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{"query":"SQL_QUERY"}' \
     --compressed
   ```

P.S. `gcloud auth print-access-token` will make it use the access token of the impersonated service account, which will allow you to run queries.

Comment: To impersonate for me it was 

`gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account SERVICE_ACCOUNT`